# Animated GIF to video converter for use in MMS, Android

Tags: android, video, gif, mms

MMS does not really support animated gifs but it does support videos.

I'm looking for an Android app that:

- Integrates ideally into the stock text messaging app's attachment button.
- Can convert an animated gif to a video and send in an MMS in one action.

It does not necessarily need to save the video for use afterwards.

Does such an app exist?

It does not have to be free, but it must not be required for the receiver to have it also.

I'd also be open to a third party SMS/MMS app if it can send animated gifs as videos.

My search fu is not good enough to find this, the results all deal with other non-text messaging apps that support gifs.